# will cron.hourly prevent my ubuntu pc from sleeping if my suspend setting is for 1 hour?

Tags: suspend, cron

I have set my 'suspend when inactive for' to 1 hour. It seems to me that because cron.hourly runs every hour, the pc will never go into suspend mode. Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the "suspend after one hour" is really a desktop thing and is just looking at human actions (keystrokes and pointer moves). You can check that the detection of inactivity works by using a different action (for instance, dimming/turning off the screen).

There are applications that can explicitly prevent the PC from going to sleep, typically file downloaders and torrent clients, so you have to review what you are running.